# Rails Helper: Current Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, logic

I've got an events collection, each doc looks like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("52d958e73f72fb1e1f000001"),
  name: "PARTY!",
  start_date: ISODate("2014-02-20T17:42:27Z"),
  end_date: ISODate("2014-03-01T17:42:27Z")
}
```

Think of this as a corporate schedule:  When a user logs in, I want them to be able to see if it's 1) Currently in the middle of an event, and if so, how many days are left. 2) If we're not currently in the midst of an event, and if so, how long to next event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a query to determine if you are now in the middle of an event and how many days left:
`Event.where(:start_date.lte => Time.now, :end_date.gte => Time.now).each{|event| puts (event.end_date-Time.now)/1.day}`

Comment: Does this mean where the start_date is after today AND end date is before today?